# php | send multidimensional array to the server

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, get

I would like to perform GET request. It looks like:

```
http://c1d.com/get?f[cid]=325&f[field_name[10][0]]=133&f[amount]=320|3600
```

I'm trying to get my params (print_r($_GET)):

```
Array
(
    [f] => Array
        (
            [cid] => 325
            [field_name[10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 133
                )

            [amount] => 320|3600
        )
)
```

The problem is in field_name array on the server.
How can I solve this?

Comment: who or what is building the url? pls show some code

Comment: There is something not right with your query string, check the brackets for `field_name`.

Comment: What result do you expect? `f[field_name[10][0]]` doesn't make a lot of sense.